# Scope and/or context in Node.js / Sails.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm running this code on a Sails.js application, and the result is an empty JSON. I've read several pages about scope and context and haven't been able to fin what I'm doing bad.

```
    var evoluciones
    HC.find({ id: req.param('id') }).then(records => {
        evoluciones = records;            
    })
    return res.json(evoluciones)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is not scope... `evoluciones` is in scope throughout the code you've listed. The query is probably returning no results.

Comment: If I put `return res.json(evoluciones)` inside `then()` returns data.

Comment: *Facepalm* I can't believe I didn't notice the promise when I commented. The problem is that your database query is **asynchronous** - the promise returned by `HC.find()` doesn't resolve until after you've returned the data. Your comment is exactly the right way to do it... call `res.json()` inside the `then` block.

Comment: The problem is that I need to do other operations outside `then()` and later call the `res.json()`, and that's where the data is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mechuda, you can try this

```
HC.find({ id: req.param('id') })
  .then(evoluciones=> { 
       // to do something
      return [evoluciones] ; 
    })
  .spread((evoluciones ) => {
          return res.json(evoluciones )
   })
  .fail( error => {
            sails.log.error(error);
            return res.negotiate(error);
   });
```